# AWS CLI is using Python 2 instead of Python 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I have installed `Python3` and `pip3` on my Macbook pro.

Running `python --version` shows `Python 3.6.3`

Running `pip --version` shows `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

however running `aws --version` shows `aws-cli/1.11.170 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.7.28`

Looks like it's using `python2`. How do I fix this?

Comment: `pip install awscli --upgrade --user`?

Answer (score 2):

Why is it really an issue?

I assume you installed the AWS CLI tool by downloading the installer directly. If you want to "fix" it then uninstall the CLI tool, and then install it through pip with `pip install awscli`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. To uninstall `pip uninstall awscli` or to  fix this `pip install awscli --upgrade --user` can also be done provided `pip3` is aliased to `pip`.  Issue is when I do `aws ec2 describe-instances` it says `An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials`. Somewhere in a forum it was mentioned that `AWS CLI` should use `python3` instead of `python2`

Comment: The AWS CLI tool works perfectly fine with Python 2. Switching it to Python 3 will not fix your authentication issue. If you can't get the CLI to work I suggest posting a new question with your exact issue. Try running `aws configure` and entering the appropriate values, then see if it still has issues.

Comment: I tried everything. Yes, I'm going to post a new question. Thanks a lot for your help.